# Weblogic console error org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "xmlns:xsi" was already specified for element "domain"

Tags: console, weblogic

I have a problem about weblogic console. I have been facing with this problem at login stage. Console gives the error:

```
INFO  configrealmlog - TurkcellConfigRealmAuthenticator Login failed for user weblogic
INFO  configrealmlog - ****
Login time for user:weblogiccompleted result=false duration=19****

Error thrown by RMI server: weblogic.management.remote.iiop.IIOPServerImpl@6cbe05 invoking: newClient(Ljava.lang.Object;
Console encountered the following error java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.lookupMBeanServerConnection(MBeanUtils.java:3209)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.getDomainRuntimeMBeanServerConnection(MBeanUtils.java:1623)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.getDomainRuntimeServiceMBean(MBeanUtils.java:1699)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer.initMBeanUtils(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:70)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer.access$000(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:20)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer$1.run(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:49)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
> 
Console encountered the following error java.lang.RuntimeException: weblogic.management.provider.EditFailedException: 
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.internal.EditServiceMBeanImpl.getDomainConfiguration(EditServiceMBeanImpl.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean.getAttribute(WLSModelMBean.java:525)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.getAttribute(JMXContextInterceptor.java:163)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$12.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:324)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.getAttribute(SecurityInterceptor.java:298)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.getAttribute(WLSMBeanServer.java:273)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$5$1.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:326)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$5.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:324)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.getAttribute(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:319)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:174)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:222)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_1032_WLStub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:504)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:380)
    at $Proxy284.getDomainConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.getDomainMBean(MBeanUtils.java:1557)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer.initMBeanUtils(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:72)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer.initMBean(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:34)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:214)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:256)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:133)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:686)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.renderInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:266)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.StrutsStubImpl.render(StrutsStubImpl.java:107)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.preRender(NetuiContent.java:292)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$6.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:428)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:727)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:146)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:168)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:211)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:196)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:47)
    at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:130)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: weblogic.management.provider.EditFailedException: 
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.EditAccessImpl.ensureBeanTreeLoaded(EditAccessImpl.java:1715)
    at weblogic.management.provider.internal.EditAccessImpl.getDomainBeanWithoutLock(EditAccessImpl.java:1158)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.internal.EditServiceMBeanImpl.getDomainConfiguration(EditServiceMBeanImpl.java:61)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "xmlns:xsi" was already specified for element "domain".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using the correct credentials? can you try with a different username/pwd?

Comment: I did but , the same error occured again. the point is, It was completely healty before I tried to add a datasource in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha, I found it. The problem was the config xml file which is under the folder "pending". It generates a damaged config.xml file which includes two definitions for xml xsi. But now, I have a different question. Why is it making that mistake in the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

your domain configuration file of your weblogic domain might be corrupt, at least the console webapp fails parsing it. This is what I 'interpret' from the method and class names in the stack.

see the [weblogic documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/domain_config/config_files.html) on where the files are located, then `ls -lahrt` the files in that dir and inspect the recently changed ones for a `<domain>` element that does declare `xmlns:xsi` twice and then correct the error in the file. I assume the `config.xml` file of the domain to be the one that is attempted to be paresed by the consoe webapp.

Comment: I am now trying it, but the interesting thing is, I did not updated any config.xml files manually. I was just tried to add a jdbc data source into the server and the error has started to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can do like this, 
1: ctrl+a,then ctrl+x,save file.
2: ctrl+v and again save it..

It might works..